# moq testing function which is using shadow property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq, nfluent

I want to test a function that gets me all users created by a user but i don't know if i can mock a shadow property.

I have a table named AppUser :

```sql
CREATE TABLE AppUser(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR(MAX) NO NULL,
   FirstName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
   CreatedBy INT NOT NULL,
   UpdatedBy INT NOT NULL,
   Action VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK_APPUSER PRIMARY KEY (Id),
   CONSTRAINT FK_APPUSER_CREATION FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES AppUser (Id),
   CONSTRAINT FK_APPUSER_MODIFICATION FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES AppUser (Id)
);
```

In my application, i created the following entity class

```
public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    ...
}
```

The `Action` columns are only used to update another database via stored procedure. It's a technical field that is not part of Business representation of a user so i created it as shadow property.

In my business layer i have a function that gets me all users created by a user :

```
public List<AppUser> GetUsersByCreator(int userCreatorId)
    => this.context.GetAll().Where(x => x.CreatedBy == userCreatorId && EF.property<string>(x, "Action") == "DELETE");
```

Until now everything is fine, the code works but i want to create some unit test using nfluent and mock but i don't know if it's possible to mock the `GetAll` function to returns a set of users specifying the shadow property to test all of my business case.

Is it possible to mock shadow property and how ?
Or should i add the `Action` field in my model ?

Comment: Why don't you have two models? One for the database (which includes the tracking fields) and one for your business domain (which does not include the tracking fields)

Comment: I obviously can do that but what's the point of overloading your entity class with a property you don't even need ? Your database model does not have to be the exact representation of your database tables. If it's not possible to write unit tests, i'll do that  though

Comment: Then I don't get it. You have a function which returns the users by their creator. Which means (at least for me) that the `CreatedBy` property should be part of your entity model since you have a logic on that, which you want to verify with unit testing. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: You're right, the example was wrong, i updated it to match my real case with action column.

Comment: I'm not using EF Core on daily basis but I would doubt that you can mock shadow properties via moq. In order to test this method I would suggest an in-memory db where you can put data directly into your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PeterCsala